# Create Cocoapods in workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods

I want to create `Pod` in a workspace which has many projects. I was following [**this**](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4585) but this again creates the pod file in project directory, not the workspace directory.
How to create `Pod` on workspace directory which can be shared across all inner projects ? Also, in that case, where would I place the Podfile ?

Comment: single pod works on whole project if you have different project in it.It works on all in it.

Comment: Could you please be more elaborative with your question.

Comment: @prabodhprakash : To be simpler, how to configure cocoapods for a workspace (a working solution).